# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import when import module

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have typescript file that will compile to javasript for the browser. It looks as follow:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/jquery-backstretch/jquery-backstretch.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/jquery-semantic/jquery-semantic.d.ts" />
import {Validator} from "classes/validator";

var main = () => {
  $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
  $(".left-half").backstretch(["../images/lotus.jpg"]);

  const val = new Validator();
  val.foo();

};

$(document)
  .ready(() => {
    main();
  });
```

The compiled version:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/jquery-backstretch/jquery-backstretch.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/jquery-semantic/jquery-semantic.d.ts" />
import {Validator} from "classes/validator";

var main = () => {
  $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
  $(".left-half").backstretch(["../images/lotus.jpg"]);

  const val = new Validator();
  val.foo();

};

$(document)
  .ready(() => {
    main();
  });
```

When I called the website, it shows me following error:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: are you transpiling to ES6? what happens if you specify `--target "es5"` when compiling (`tsc -t "es5" app.ts`)?

Comment: Yes I am trying to transpiling to es6. I have to transpile to es6 because rxjs support only es6. Why es6 should work or not?

Comment: The chrome browser is pretty up to date, the error can not be on browser.

Comment: V8 doesn't yet support the ES6 import syntax. Edit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import states that no browser implements it yet. It's possible that the syntax definition is still a draft, but I think they finalized it recently.

Comment: so I have to convert typescript to es5?

Comment: no, you don't have to, a lot of ES6 features are actually supported already (see https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). You just can't use the `import` syntax yet, but you can use something else for module imports, like [require.js](http://www.requirejs.org/).

Comment: In my tsconfig file as target, what do I have to write?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html => `{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es5" } }`